# How to get the element type of each container passed to variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template function and I'm passing a sequence of `std::vector`s to it. For each `std::vector` object I need to get the type of its elements, in order to do some operations on it, like retrieving compile time constants ex `T::SIZE`, or check its size `sizeof(T)`. Here is the two approaches I tried:

```
template<typename T...>
void foo(std::vector<T>...args) {
     auto f = [](auto x){
          size_t size = sizeof(T);
          int var = T::SIZE;
     };
     (f(args),...);;
 }

 template<typename T...>
 void foo(T...args) {
     auto f = [](auto x){
          using U = typename x.value_type;
          size_t size = sizeof(U);
          int var = U::SIZE;
     };
     (f(args),...);;
}
```

With the second approach I tried to abstract the `std::vector`'s type away, and instead get the type by using `std::vector::value_type` method.

And then I pass the values:

```
std::vector<A>a;
std::vector<B>b;
std::vector<C>c;
foo(a, b, c);
```

With the first approach compiler gives me:

```
error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’: auto f = ...
```

With the second approach I get:

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘x’ using U = typename x.value_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do something like:

```cpp
template<typename ...T>
void foo(T...args) {
     auto f = [](auto x){
          using U = typename decltype(x)::value_type;
          int size = sizeof(U);
          int var = sizeof(U);
     };
     (f(args),...);;
}
```

If later on you'd like to change the lambda to accept references, such as `f = [](auto&& x)`, you'd have to use `std::decay_t`, since the `decltype(x)` will give you a reference type, and a reference type does not have any nested type members:

```cpp
template<typename ...T>
void foo(T...args) {
     auto f = [](auto&& x){
          using U = typename std::decay_t<decltype(x)>::value_type;
          int size = sizeof(U);
          int var = sizeof(U);
     };
     (f(args),...);;
}
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/fPr4Gh

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because it includes the case when passing references which is really helpful.

Comment: Could you explain why we need to use `std::decay_t` when passing by reference?

Comment: @LennyWhite See edit. `decltype(x)` gives you `x`'s declared type. If such type is a reference, you'd have to remove the reference so that you can access its nested types. You can use `remove_reference` as well, but that is harder to spell.

Comment: I see thanks! For some reason I don't seem to find documentation on `std::decay_t` only on `std::decay` and `std::remove_reference`. Just out of curiousity's sake trying to use the last two gives me `no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class std::decay<const std::vector<MyClass> >&’`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The template parameter should be declared as `typename... T` instead of `typename T...`.
2. You should get the type from argument `x`, then get `value_type` from it, e.g. `typename decltype(x)::value_type`.
3. In the 1st case, you should get infos from argument `x` too, similarily with the 2nd one.

With the 1st one,

```
template<typename... T>
void foo(std::vector<T>...args) {
     auto f = [](auto x){
          using U = typename decltype(x)::value_type;
          int size = sizeof(U);
          int var = U::VAR;
     };
     (f(args),...);;
}
```

The 2nd one:

```
template<typename... T>
void foo(T...args) {
     auto f = [](auto x){
          using U = typename decltype(x)::value_type;
          int size = sizeof(U);
          int var = U::VAR;
     };
     (f(args),...);;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/84lyfk7OGAx8CDOj)